# Group By Age calculated from date of birth SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am trying to show a count for each age which is calculated from a Date of Birth column but the problem is it will only group by date of birth so there are a lot of duplicate ages being shown.  Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(hh, p.p_dob, GETDATE())/8766 AS Age,
    COUNT(DISTINCT s.s_studentreference) AS 'Count'    
FROM 
    moduleenrolment e
INNER JOIN 
    module m ON m.m_id = e.e_module
INNER JOIN 
    person p ON p.p_id = e.e_student
INNER JOIN 
    student s ON s.s_id = p.p_id
WHERE 
    m.m_reference LIKE '11%'
    AND LEN(m.m_reference) <= 12
    AND e.e_status IN ('A', 'W', 'C')
GROUP BY 
    p.p_dob
ORDER BY 
    p.p_dob DESC
```

This is a sample for the results

```
12  1
13  1
14  1
14  1
14  1
14  1
14  1
14  1
14  1
14  1
14  1
```

What I was looking for was

```
12 1
13 1
14 9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group by and order by `DATEDIFF(hh, p.p_dob, GETDATE())/8766` instead of `p.p_dob`

By grouping by `p.p_dob`, you're effectively grouping by the unique date of birth instead of the calculated age.

Comment: Column "person.p_dob" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Like I said, Group by **and** order by `DATEDIFF(hh, p.p_dob, GETDATE())/8766`

Answer (score 1):

Check RANK()/DENSE_RANK() functions if available on the version of SQL Server you are using. It will help you to rank within the age group. You partition your query by age and rank it. The same age will have the same rank, lk all rows with age 14 will always have rank 1, 15 - rank 2 etc...

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by the actual date of birth, not by the age.
Not sure if it'll work, but try to put your calculation in your group by statement

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT TRUNC (MONTHS_BETWEEN (SYSDATE, SS.DATE_OF_BIRTH) / 12)
from (YOUR TABLE) SS
```

---

Answer (score -1):

Some time your date function is not working in your Oracle database. That time you don't panic; try this:

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT CEIL(ROUND(SYSDATE - HIRE_DATE)/365.22) AS AGE , HIRE_DATE
    FROM EMP_DUPLICATE WHERE EMP_ID = 100 )
```